# there are some integer pairs $(m,n)$ that satisfy $\frac{m^2+mn+n^2}{m+2n}=\frac{13}{3}$ Find the value of $m + 2n$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

there are some integer pairs $(m,n)$ that satisfy $$\frac{m^2+mn+n^2}{m+2n}=\frac{13}{3}.$$ Find the value of $m + 2n.$

I tried expressing the numerator in terms of $m+2n$ but it resulted in nothing remotely useful

hints or suggestions would be appreciated aswell as solutions.

from the 2019 SAIMC
https://chiuchang.org/imc/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2019/08/2019-IWYMIC-answer.x17381.pdf

Comment: Well, trial and error yields a pair $(m,n)$ that works pretty quickly...but of course there could be others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can rewrite the equation $\frac{m^2+mn+n^2}{m+2n}=\frac{13}{3}$ in the form: $3m^2+3mn+3n^2=13(m+2n)$ and so $3m^2+m(3n-13)-26n+3n^2=0$. Using the quadratic formula: $$m=\frac{-(3n-13)\pm\sqrt{(3n-13)^2-4\cdot3\cdot(3n^2-26n)}}{6}$$

The polynomial $(3n-13)^2-4\cdot3\cdot(3n^2-26n)$ is positive only if $\frac{13}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{26}}{3\sqrt3}\leq x \leq \frac{13}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{26}}{3\sqrt3}$. The only cases when the polynomial is a square are $n=2$ $\land$ $m=5$ or $n=7$ $\land$ $m=-5$.

Let $A_1=m_1+2n_1=5+2\cdot 2=9$ and $A_2=m_2+2n_2=-3$.

Comment: $m+2n$ has to be divisible by $3$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Corrected.

Comment: can you please explain what you did with the $\frac{13}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{26}}{3\sqrt3}\le x  \le \frac{13}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{26}}{3\sqrt3}$ I don't understand the reasoning behind it

Comment: @Tyrone: simply put: $(3n-13)^2-4\cdot3\cdot(3n^2-26n)\geq0$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$3m^2+(3n-13)m+3n^2-26n=0,$$ which gives
$$(3n-13)^2-12(3n^2-26n)\geq0$$ or
$$27n^2-234n-169\leq0,$$ which gives not so many cases:
$$n\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}.$$
Can you end it now?

I got only  $n=2$ gives $m=5$ and $n=7$ gives $m=-5.$